# Read comma separated values from the column and use the comma separated values in the where condition in same query in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 Tables that I am joining and grab some record(s). I have a column in TABLE1 which has COMMA separated values. I want to sperate the values in two part and put these values in WHERE clause. For example, the column value has '1,3' value and I want to split these values and use it in where condition.

The requirement is to get the record(s) based on these comma separated values. I want to fetch the records(s) whose start value is 1 and last value is 3 based on that column value.

[image]

I want to write a query to get the records based on comma separated values but I don't know how to split the column value and put comma separated value in the where clause.

e.g.

```
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range
FROM **TABLE1**
JOIN **TABLE2** ON TABLE1.T1Id = TABLE2.T2Id
JOIN **TABLE3** ON TABLE1.T1Id = TABLE3.T3Id 
WHERE EMPKey = "CONDITION1" AND SALARY = 'CONDITION2' AND EMP_Range has first string as '1' AND Last String as '3'
```

How can I write this condition in SQL (EMP_Range has first string as '1' AND Last String as '3')?

What should be my best approach or SQL query.

I am using SQLLite. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed SQL Server tag since you are using SQLite

Comment: This is the type of problem you run into when your database is poorly designed, Combining multiple values into the same column when you're going to need to use them independently in the future is simply bad thinking on the database designer's part. Whoever did that design should buy a good book or find a good online tutorial on database design and normalization, and then modify your tables and clean up the data. Unless that's done, you're going to face endless struggles going forward.

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted/tabular text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Will there always be 2 elements? Simply `EMP_Range = '1,3'`?

Comment: @June7, Yes. There would be 2 elements only in this column.

Comment: Well, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @June7, Sorry I did not get. Can you please suggest again?

Comment: I show criteria expression in my earlier comment.

Comment: @June7 no, it didn't work. My requirement is break the comma separated string and compare individually with the column.

Comment: "Didn't work" means what - wrong results? "Compare individually with the column" should provide same results. What results would you expect from the sample data? Can use substring() function to separate elements. `substring(EMP_Range, 1, 1) = 1 AND substring(EMP_Range, 3, 1) = 3`. Why is this a requirement? Is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 0):

As according to the comment *Yes. There would be 2 elements only in this column* then you can either

1. extract the individual vales from the EMP_Range column and compare each, or
2. combine the search vales into a CSV

***1 Extracting the individual values from the EMP_Range column for the WHERE clause***

For the first you can utilise the [substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) functions to extract the two parts/values

1. part/value 1 would be the substring of the EMP_Range from the 1st character up until the position of the character before the comma.
2. part/value 2 would be the substring of the EMP_Range from after the comma

So you could have

```
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE substr(EMP_Range,1,instr(EMP_Range,',')-1) = '1' AND substr(EMP_Range,instr(EMP_RANGE,',')+1) = '3';
```

- other WHERE conditions omitted for brevity

***2 Combining the two search values***

This is simply a matter of concatenating, using the `||` [operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes), the two search values with a comma between the two. e.g.

```
SELECT EMPName,EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE EMP_range = /*first value>>>>>*/'1'||','||/*last value>>>>>>*/'3';
```

- other WHERE conditions omitted for brevity
- of course the values could be combined programmatically and passed as a single value

**Demo**

The following demonstrates both for various ranges including ranges that have larger values:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (EMPId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, EMPName TEXT, EMP_Range TEXT, Salary REAL);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES (1,'Andy','1,3',50000),(2,'Ros','2,3',60000),(3,'KC','3,3',45000),(4,'Keddy','1,3',35000);
/* Add a row with larger ranges */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES (null,'Fred','123456,987654',25000);
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE substr(EMP_Range,1,instr(EMP_Range,',')-1) = '1' AND substr(EMP_Range,instr(EMP_RANGE,',')+1) = '3';
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE substr(EMP_Range,1,instr(EMP_Range,',')-1) = '2' AND substr(EMP_Range,instr(EMP_RANGE,',')+1) = '3';
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE substr(EMP_Range,1,instr(EMP_Range,',')-1) = '3' AND substr(EMP_Range,instr(EMP_RANGE,',')+1) = '3';
SELECT EMPName, EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE substr(EMP_Range,1,instr(EMP_Range,',')-1) = '123456' AND substr(EMP_Range,instr(EMP_RANGE,',')+1) = '987654';
/**/
SELECT EMPName,EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE EMP_range = /*first value>>>>>*/'1'||','||/*last value>>>>>>*/'3';
SELECT EMPName,EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE EMP_range = /*first value>>>>>*/'2'||','||/*last value>>>>>>*/'3';
SELECT EMPName,EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE EMP_range = /*first value>>>>>*/'3'||','||/*last value>>>>>>*/'3';
SELECT EMPName,EMP_Range FROM table1 WHERE EMP_range = /*first value>>>>>*/'123456'||','||/*last value>>>>>>*/'987654';
/* Cleanup DEMO */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
```

This results in 8 results as per (4 for method 1 and 4 for method 2):-

The first

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Andy    1,3
Keddy   1,3
```

The 2nd

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Ros     2,3
```

The 3rd

```
EMPName EMP_Range
KC      3,3
```

The 4th (larger ranges)

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Fred    123456,987654
```

The 5th (combining the search arguments) i.e. identical result to the first

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Andy    1,3
Keddy   1,3
```

The 6th, identical to the 2nd

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Ros     2,3
```

The 7th, identical to the 3rd

```
EMPName EMP_Range
KC      3,3
```

Finally the 8th, identical to the 4th

```
EMPName EMP_Range
Fred    123456,987654
```

[DB Fiddle of the above](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f2S5xX6bYiLgUU7LGS7Jd2/0)